# I want to create a new disk on which to install programs

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, home-directory, transfer

before installing Ubuntu I want to create a disc where the programs in Ubuntu will be installed. I have two discs, SSD and HDD. I will install Ubuntu on the SSD, but I want to create a separate HDD disc and store the programs to be installed on the HDD. If I create a /home folder on the HDD before installing, will the programs I install be installed on the HDD? Please tell me if this is possible. Because my Windows was installed on SSD, but I could install programs in a directory on HDD and that was great, but in Ubuntu I think it is very difficult for a beginner to do it afterwards, so I want to do it before installation.

Comment: This is not possible, as Ubuntu (Linux in general) share more common program and system files with each other. That is, it has one version of these shared files. There are exceptions based on installation methods such as snap, flatpack, appimage etc. apps installed using these methods, don't share program files with others. The /home folder generally don't have programs. So moving /home to the HDD won't do what you want.

Comment: What do you think would be an advantage of separating program packages from the rest of the OS?

Comment: not a smart idea. if either of the disks fails you wrecked your system, what you want is also not portable so useless in that regard. keep a system on your quickest hard drive and personal files on your normal one

Comment: Even in Windows which of course this is not Ubuntu some data for every program gets put in certain default directories and you can not control this.

Comment: My free space on SSD is 40 gb and my free space on HDD is 500 GB I want to install Ubuntu on SSD and install programmes on HDD. For example, I cannot install a 60 gb game on SSD via Steam on Ubuntu because I have no space, is it not possible to install it on HDD?

Comment: Non-system programs may allow you to install wherever you want.  Steam allows this designation of library location.

Comment: @ubfan1 I can't install any programme in a directory of my choice on the HDD?

Comment: Not without great difficulty, and for no clear reason.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to the answers given above. What you could to and what might work for special programs where the installation location is known and has a separate folder for that (I don't know if that applies to steam): you could move that folder to you HDD (before installing all the steam apps) and create a link to that folder in the old location. I wouldn't do that for snaps and other programs the system might need. However, if you do it for programs the system does not need, your system will be intact even if the HDD fails.